# Puppeteer Failed To Launch on Linux Shared Hosting

Tags: node.js, linux, puppeteer

This is the error I get trying to launch puppeteer.

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!\n/home2/eventeo1/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-1108766/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting\n\n    at Interface.onClose (/home2/eventeo1/nodevenv/public_html/eventeos/api/16/lib/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:262:24)\n    at Interface.emit (node:events:525:35)\n    at Interface.close (node:readline:590:8)\n    at Socket.onend (node:readline:280:10)\n    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

But puppeteer works fine on my local(windows). I`ve had some solutions relating to ubuntu but it didn't work for me.

I tried running this command on my linux server `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` but I get this error `bash: sudo: command not found` or without sudo `bash: apt-get: command not found` and with rpm `bash: apt-get: command not found`.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *apt*-get not app-get. apt = Advanced Packaging Tool

Comment: Yh `apt-get` is what I meant, I have edited the question.

Comment: What OS are you running? Did you mangle your env variables? What do you get when you enter `echo $PATH`?